# Integrate app with in-built barcode scanner

Tags: android, android-intent, barcode-scanner

I am creating an app on an Android tablet that needs to scan barcodes and get the result. The tablet I am using has an in-built scanner, as well as the camera.

I have tried to use the Zxing Lib for this but this uses the camera on the tablet, rather than call the Scanner.

How can I find the actual Intent I need to use to call the Scanner directly from inside my app?

There is a Barcode Utility app pre-installed on the tablet, with a basic screen for capturing barcode data, I think that I probably should call this, via an Intent, in my app. But again how do I know the Intent I need to use to call this utility app?

Comment: What is the mark and model of your tablet ? Did you try to find a developer documentation on the constructor's website ?

Comment: Its a Getac Z710, I have contacted the company Support guys, but have to wait for up to 3 days for a response.

Comment: As far as I can tell I shouldnt need to use a Lib like Zxing as there is already the scanner there and a utility app that I imagine I can call in the background and have the data passed back. But I don't know how to call this utility app.

Comment: The manual says: _NOTE: For enhanced applications and customization of the barcode reader, contact your authorized Getac dealer._ Thats what you should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may check whether it is a device which has its own barcode scanner by doing something like 
    if (android.os.Build.MANUFACTURER == "Pegatron") {
        //Do what you are doing now
    } else {
        //Use the XZing Intent to provide your service for other devices
    }

Of course you have to hardcode all devices with a built-in scanner but I guess there are not many which have such a feature. You could even specify the devices you want to execute their built-in scanner logic by using `android.os.Build.MODEL`. Check this [info page from dev docs for further details](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html).